# Function not getting called right

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I'm trying to call my updateDisplay method through a for loop to set the text for the corresponding index, but in the output only the 5th index code is getting run.

Here is the for loop that I'm calling in my fragment's onCreateView();

```
private int mIndexofDays;

for(int i =1; i < 6; i++) {
        DateTime nextday = mDateTime.plusDays(i);
        long time = nextday.getMillis() / 1000;
        getForecast(mLattitude, mLongitude, time);
        mIndexofDays = i;
   }
```

Here is the getForecast() method:

```
 private void getForecast(double latitude, double longitude, long time)
{
    String apiKey =  getResources().getString(R.string.api_key);


    String forecastUrl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + apiKey +
            "/" + latitude + "," + longitude + "," + time;





            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(forecastUrl)
                    .build();
            Call call = client.newCall(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {



                        }
                    });


                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                            mWeather = getCurrentDetails(jsonData);
                            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Running....");
                                    updateDisplay();


                                }
                            });

                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Response not successful");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, " IOException caught: ", e);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "JSON exception caught: ", e);

                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

And here is the updateDisplay() method:

private void updateDisplay() {

```
    if(mIndexofDays == 1) {
        mDayOfWeek1.setText(mDateTime.plusDays(1).dayOfWeek().getAsShortText());
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(mWeather.getIconId());
        mDayOfWeekImage1.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        mHighTemp1.setText(mWeather.getTemperatureMax() + "");
        mLowTemp1.setText(mWeather.getTemperatureMin() + "");
    }
    if(mIndexofDays == 2) {
        mDayOfWeek2.setText(mDateTime.plusDays(2).dayOfWeek().getAsShortText());
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(mWeather.getIconId());
        mDayOfWeekImage2.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        mHighTemp2.setText(mWeather.getTemperatureMax() + "");
    }

    if(mIndexofDays == 3) {
        mDayOfWeek3.setText(mDateTime.plusDays(3).dayOfWeek().getAsShortText());
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(mWeather.getIconId());
        mDayOfWeekImage3.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        mHighTemp3.setText(mWeather.getTemperatureMax() + "");
    }
    if(mIndexofDays == 4) {
        mDayOfWeek4.setText(mDateTime.plusDays(4).dayOfWeek().getAsShortText());
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(mWeather.getIconId());
        mDayOfWeekImage4.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        mHighTemp4.setText(mWeather.getTemperatureMax() + "");
    }
   if(mIndexofDays == 5) {
       mDayOfWeek5.setText(mDateTime.plusDays(5).dayOfWeek().getAsShortText());
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(mWeather.getIconId());
        mDayOfWeekImage5.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        mHighTemp5.setText(mWeather.getTemperatureMax() + "");

    }
    else
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Index to high!!!");
    }
}
```

From the logs I can see that "Running" is getting called but updateDisplay never updates for 1-4 indexes only for the 5th index.

I am a very novice programmer, so please tell me on what is wrong with my style and better methods to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

modify updateDisplay and pass a copy of mIndexofDays as a parameter, and this should work. I can provide the actual implementation code but I encourage you to try it first yourself.

hope this helps :)

Comment: I already tried that solution but that didnt work for me, maybe I was doing it wrong, can you show me how?

Comment: Nvm, I tried it and it now works, but there is another problem, that I think is with the api. I'll just ask it here in case anyone can provide insight. When I refresh the app or reload the values for the weather they come out sometimes very unaccurate. For example reloading tomorrow's weather sometimes shows up as -7 and sometimes with the correct amount.

Answer (score 0):

change your for loop like this

```
for(int i =1; i < 6; i++) {
        mIndexofDays = i;
        DateTime nextday = mDateTime.plusDays(i);
        long time = nextday.getMillis() / 1000;
        getForecast(mLattitude, mLongitude, time, mIndexofDays); // new parameter: mIndexofDays
}
```

catch the parameter mIndexofDays in getForecast method and pass it through updateDisplay method. Next, use the value of mIndexofDays to compare in your if...else statements. You can use Log method or time delay method to check if it's actually working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue is that your `updateDisplay()` is called only when you receive response in `onResponse()`. Now, by the time this happens your loop has already ended and the value of `mIndexofDays` is `5`. To fix the issue one of the things you can do is to pass the value of `mIndexofDays` to your `getForecast()` method:

```
private void getForecast(double latitude, double longitude, long time, int indexOfDays) {
    ...
    updateDisplay(numberOfDays); 
    ...
}
```

You also need to change your `updateDisplay()` method:

```
private void updateDisplay(int indexOfDays) {
    ...
}
```

Also, get rid of the `mIndexOfDays` instance variable since you [probably] don't need it anywhere.